# rake loaderror “rake db:create”

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, cucumber

While running the command

```
rake db: create
```

I'm getting the error below:

```
/home/supranimbus12/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rake-10.4.2/bin/rake:31:in `require': cannot load such file -- rake (LoadError)
    from /home/supranimbus12/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rake-10.4.2/bin/rake:31:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/supranimbus12/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0@global/bin/rake:23:in `load'
    from /home/supranimbus12/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0@global/bin/rake:23:in `<main>'
    from /home/supranimbus12/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0@global/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `eval'
    from /home/supranimbus12/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0@global/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `<main>'
```

Comment: let me know if the solution given below works?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
bundle install
bundle exec rake db:create
bundle exec rake db:migrate
```